# Convert Entity to array in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get a multi-dimensional array from an Entity.

[Symfony Serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) can already convert to XML, JSON, YAML etc. but not to an array.

I need to convert because I want have a clean `var_dump`. I now have entity with few connections and is totally unreadable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Doctrine2 result object as an associative array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259256/how-to-get-a-doctrine2-result-object-as-an-associative-array)

Comment: i dont want get restult as array - i use it as entity and need in other plaace convert to array.

Comment: There are much better ways to debug your application than "var_dumps". Try use xdebug - this tool as a debuger is really great.

Comment: Prefer use this class http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Util.Debug.html with method dump

Comment: Why do you want clean var dumps? If you are just using it to debug then (as @Cyprian says, there are better ways to go about it. If you are looking to use `var dumps` as a part of your coding then you really shouldn't. Pictures of cats however...

Comment: because var_dump is too big - usually i want get partial informations - entities have many realtions so var_dump give my too big text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually convert doctrine entities into an array using the built in serializer. I actually just wrote a blog post about this today:
https://skylar.tech/detect-doctrine-entity-changes-without/

You basically call the normalize function and it will give you what you want:

```
$entityAsArray = $this->serializer->normalize($entity, null);
```

I recommend checking my post for more information about some of the quirks but this should do exactly what you want without any additional dependencies or dealing with private/protected fields.

Comment: Is there annotation to tell that some property should be returned as object without serialisation? My object has properties (object, stream). I want to convert Object to array of objects.

Comment: If some property is a strem then you will get error: An unexpected value could not be normalized: "stream" resource. Easiest way is to add @Ignore annotation. I need to export it as object

Comment: Current Symfony serializer requires the second parameter to be of type `string`: `public function serialize(mixed $data, string $format, array $context = []): string;`, so this will, unfortunately, not work anymore and needs to be revisited.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, it is possible to cast objects to arrays like following:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public $bar = 'barValue';
}

$foo = new Foo();

$arrayFoo = (array) $foo;

var_dump($arrayFoo);
```

This [will produce](https://3v4l.org/ELLJA) something like:

```
array(1) {
    ["bar"]=> string(8) "barValue"
}
```

If you have got private and protected attributes see this link : https://ocramius.github.io/blog/fast-php-object-to-array-conversion/

## Get entity in array format from repository query

In your EntityRepository you can select your entity and specify you want an array with `getArrayResult()` method.
For more informations see [Doctrine query result formats documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats).

```
public function findByIdThenReturnArray($id){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT e FROM YourOwnBundle:Entity e WHERE e.id = :id")
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

---

If all that doesn't fit you should go see the PHP documentation about [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.
It retrieves the attributes this way : `echo $entity['Attribute'];`

Comment: getArrayResult not convert Entity to array - i have entity and want convert it to array.

Comment: @GrekHmhmm I've updated my answer : **Use get_object_vars($entity)**

Comment: get_object_vars($entity)  returns empty on my app 2.6

Comment: If it return empty it's probably because your request return empty result. Do a "var_dump" of your result request

Comment: get_object_vars won't work if the properties are private

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8 allows us to cast object to array:

```
$var = (array)$someObj;
```

It is important for object to have only public properties otherwise you will get weird array keys:

```
<?php
class bag {
    function __construct( 
        public ?bag $par0 = null, 
        public string $par1 = '', 
        protected string $par2 = '', 
        private string $par3 = '') 
    {
        
    }
}
  
// Create myBag object
$myBag = new bag(new bag(), "Mobile", "Charger", "Cable");
echo "Before conversion : \n";
var_dump($myBag);
  
// Converting object to an array
$myBagArray = (array)$myBag;
echo "After conversion : \n";
var_dump($myBagArray);
?>
```

The output is following:

```
Before conversion : 
object(bag)#1 (4) {
  ["par0"]=>               object(bag)#2 (4) {
    ["par0"]=>                      NULL
    ["par1"]=>                      string(0) ""
    ["par2":protected]=>            string(0) ""
    ["par3":"bag":private]=>        string(0) ""
  }
  ["par1"]=>               string(6) "Mobile"
  ["par2":protected]=>     string(7) "Charger"
  ["par3":"bag":private]=> string(5) "Cable"
}


After conversion : 
array(4) {
  ["par0"]=>      object(bag)#2 (4) {
    ["par0"]=>                  NULL
    ["par1"]=>                  string(0) ""
    ["par2":protected]=>        string(0) ""
    ["par3":"bag":private]=>    string(0) ""
  }
  ["par1"]=>      string(6) "Mobile"
  ["�*�par2"]=>   string(7) "Charger"
  ["�bag�par3"]=> string(5) "Cable"
}
```

This method has a benefit comparing to Serialiser normalizing -- this way you can convert Object to array of objects, not array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried the 2 other answers. Both did not work very smoothly.

- The `$object = (array) $object;` added alot of extra text in my key
  names.
- The serializer didn't use my `active` property because it did not have `is` in front of it and is a `boolean`. It also changed the sequence of my data and the data itself.

So I created a new function in my entity:

```php
/**
 * Converts and returns current user object to an array.
 * 
 * @param $ignores | requires to be an array with string values matching the user object its private property names.
 */
public function convertToArray(array $ignores = [])
{
    $user = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'username' => $this->username,
        'roles' => $this->roles,
        'password' => $this->password,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'amount_of_contracts' => $this->amount_of_contracts,
        'contract_start_date' => $this->contract_start_date,
        'contract_end_date' => $this->contract_end_date,
        'contract_hours' => $this->contract_hours,
        'holiday_hours' => $this->holiday_hours,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'active' => $this->active,
    ];

    // Remove key/value if its in the ignores list.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ignores); $i++) { 
        if (array_key_exists($ignores[$i], $user)) {
            unset($user[$ignores[$i]]);
        }
    }

    return $user;
}
```

I basicly added all my properties to the new `$user` array and made an extra `$ignores` variable that makes sure properties can be ignored (in case you don't want all of them).

You can use this in your controller as following:

```php
$user = new User();
// Set user data...

// ID and password are being ignored.
$user = $user->convertToArray(["id", "password"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this trait to the entity:

```
<?php

namespace Model\Traits;

/**
 * ToArrayTrait
 */
trait ToArrayTrait
{
    /**
     * toArray
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray(): array
    {
        $zval = get_object_vars($this);

        return($zval);
    }
}
```

Then you cat do:

$myValue = $entity->toArray();