# From object to array in doctrine2

Tags: php, object, serialization, doctrine-orm, extract

I'm using [Doctrine 2 ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) to map my SQL table into objects.
Is there a support method like `asArray` which converts my objects into an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine entity object to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158549/doctrine-entity-object-to-array)

Comment: Didn't see any solution in that topic :(

Comment: Which php framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any framework

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `getArrayResult` method that is mentioned here inside [the Doctrine 2 documentation chapter **14.7.4.2. Array Hydration**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration):

```
$array = $query->getArrayResult();
```

It is a short notation for, and does exactly the same as, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25158920/1697459) that that @Joucks is pointing to in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954363/from-object-to-array-in-doctrine2/41956249#comment71089182_41954363):

```
$array = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

---

But you don't necessarily have to look at specific Doctrine ORM solutions for such serializing functionality. You could also look at solutions that come with the PHP framework that you are using.

### Zend-Framework

For example if you use Zend-Framework you could implement [the `ArraySerializableInterface`](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Stdlib.ArraySerializableInterface.html) inside the objects that you want to be able to serialize to an array.

This interface includes an `getArrayCopy` method that should return the object serialized to an array.

You can read more about `ArraySerializable` inside the [Zend-Framework 2 `Zend\Stdlib` documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html)

### Symfony

Symfony ships with [this Serializer component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html).

---

For other frameworks I expect they are shipped with similar interfaces/solutions.